# How can I get the sitecore field from an object property, mapped by glassmapper?

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

We are using Glass Mapper with Sitecore, with our models we can get the values of sitecore fields. But I want to easily get the sitecore fields(sitecore field type) by using the model without hardcoding any strings (when using `GetProperty()`, you need the property name string ) into the method.

So I wrote this thing to achieve this, however I am not happy with 2 types need to be passed in when using it since it looks awful when you have a long model identifier.

```
   public static string SitecoreFieldName<T, TU>(Expression<Func<TU>> expr)
    {
         var body = ((MemberExpression)expr.Body);
         var attribute = (typeof(T).GetProperty(body.Member.Name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SitecoreFieldAttribute), false)[0]) as SitecoreFieldAttribute;
         return attribute.FieldName;
    }
```

The most ideal way is be able to get it like this `Model.SomeProperty.SitecoreField()`. However I can't figure out how to do the refection from there. Because that can will be a extension for any type.

Thanks!

Comment: I know I should check null array. so ignore this one.

Comment: So what is your question? Looks pretty simple and generic to me..

Comment: The question is to improve it more. In this case, you need to pass in 2 types to make it work, which doesn't look very good on aspx page when you use it in a data bind context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static string SitecoreFieldName<TModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, object>> field)
{
    var body = field.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (body == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var attribute = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(body.Member.Name)
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SitecoreFieldAttribute), true)
        .FirstOrDefault() as SitecoreFieldAttribute;

    return attribute != null
        ? attribute.FieldName
        : null;
}
```

Note that I put `inherit=true` on the `GetCustomAttributes` method call.
Otherwise inherited attributes are ignored.

Comment: Sorry I cant upvote yet but thanks! it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why my question got down-voted. So you think it's perfect code already?

With help of another senior developer, I improved it today so it doesn't need 2 types any more and much clearer on usage syntax:

```
public static Field GetSitecoreField<T>(T model, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression) where T : ModelBase
    {
        var body = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body);
        var attributes = typeof(T).GetProperty(body.Member.Name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SitecoreFieldAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Any())
        {
            var attribute = attributes[0] as SitecoreFieldAttribute;
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                return model.Item.Fields[attribute.FieldName];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and I can just call it by doing this:

```
GetSitecoreField(Container.Model<SomeModel>(), x => x.anyField)
```

Hope it helps anyone who is using Glass Mapper with Sitecore and want to get current sitecore field from model property.